# Organising a list by ids based on an array - jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, list, sorting

I have a dynamically created ul with li I have to organise following a certain arbitrary order.

This is an example of the generated HTML:

```
<ul id="myUl">
    <li id="myId_15" class="myId_class">A list item</li>
    <li id="myId_264" class="myId_class">Another list item</li>
    <li id="myId_573" class="myId_class">Yet another list item</li>
</ul>
```

This is the jQuery I've managed so far for this part :

```
var slicedCompIds = ["15","573","264"];

$.each(slicedCompIds, function(i){
        $('#myUl').append($('#myUl li').attr('id', 'myId_' + slicedCompIds[i]));
})
```

The goal is to reorganize or sort the list by id using the order in the "slicedCompIds" array. It wont be in a numerical ascending order, and will most likely be random.

My code at the moment is producing this :

```
<ul id="myUl">
    <li id="myId_264" class="myId_class">A list item</li>
    <li id="myId_264" class="myId_class">Another list item</li>
    <li id="myId_264" class="myId_class">Yet another list item</li>
</ul>
```

It keeps the same order, but just replaces the id with the last id in the "slicedCompIds" array.

I'm really having trouble wrapping my head around the logic I have to apply for this part, hence why I'm asking for ideas. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: that is because append executes only in the next stack cycle. Before which the iteration is completed and the value of id is set to last value in the array.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your code is because in the `append()` call you're getting all the `li` elements then changing the `id` attribute of the first one before appending them back in their original locations.

To amend the logic to do what you require you need to select each element individually by it's `id` based on the value in the array, then `append()` only that element. Try this:

```js
var slicedCompIds = ["15","573","264"];

slicedCompIds.forEach(function(value, i){
  $('#myUl').append($('#myId_' + value));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUl">
    <li id="myId_15" class="myId_class">A list item</li>
    <li id="myId_264" class="myId_class">Another list item</li>
    <li id="myId_573" class="myId_class">Yet another list item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly it! Ugh I feel dumb, feels like a Monday morning. I'll accept your answer, there's just a cooldown apparently.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)